# Setting cookie jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie using [jquery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) on a `toggle()` with bootstrap grid. I just don't know how to set the cookie and cannot get me head around it.

any ideas how to do this with my current code?

```
$('.grid-toggle a').click(function(event) {
    $('.list-products li').removeClass('col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-lg-6');
    if ($(this).hasClass('three')) {
        $('.list-products li').addClass('col-md-4 col-lg-4');
    }

    if ($(this).hasClass('two')) { //for less products
        $('.list-products li').addClass('col-md-6 col-lg-6');    
    }

    return false;
});

// Button
//
$(".two, .three").click(function()
{                     
   $(".two, .three").toggle();
});
```

This allows me to toggle my current product grid:

```
<ul class="list-products row">
  <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  one
  </li>
  <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  two
  </li> 
  <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
 three
  </li>
  <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
   four
  </li> 
</ul>
```

I set the toggle with this:

```
<div class="grid-toggle">
 <a class="two" href="#">2</a>
 <a class="three" style="display:none;" href="#">4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: There are plenty of "jquery cookie" libraries each with several versions...link to the one you are using, please.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, but why not simply use `document.cookie` in vannila JS?